# How to embed Markdown in a python file used as a jupyter notebook in PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I prefer to create/edit *jupyter* notebooks directly within python using `#%%` cell delimiters.  PyCharm is perfectly happy to identify the cells in this manner.  But how do we specify that a cell is a non-python specifically *markdown*?

[image]

Is there something similar to code fences e.g.

```
#%% {markdown}
```

Or is there a completely different construct available for this support?

Comment: did you tried `#%% md` ?

Comment: @vb_rises  I do see that your suggestion for `#%% md` is partially working. Would you be able to craete an answer showing the entire process of converting to `.ipynb` ?  I tried couple of packages including https://github.com/gatsoulis/py2ipynb but it is not working yet.

Comment: I guess I won't be able to show the entire process of converting to .ipynb. I guess it would be mostly through some already developed the package only. Why you want to do this when you can easily write .ipynb? Also, a question not related to this post, I see that you are using big data stack (especially spark), would be able to recommend some learning path for it. I am very much interested in it but not able to follow any path. Thanks

Comment: @vb_rises  OK  I am figuring out the e2e using `jupytext` (see answer below).  I prefer writing `.py` over `.ipynb` due to proper software engineering practices: keep python modular and not lost within notebooks.   On the other topic:  Looks like you already found some of my `spark` related answers ;) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1056563+[apache-spark]

Comment: if you would write python and then later want to convert it to ipynb, you would be spending more time on resolving the syntax stuff instead of writing business/useful code directly in ipynb. I had seen your answers, but I am asking a kind of learning path (book, online course, etc), where first I can clear basics, then practice and then see answers in case of issue.

Comment: "writing business/useful code" . My work tends to re-use the same code a lot: so it's different than throwing some code into a jupyter notebook running it a couple of times and then forgetting about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `jupytext` is going to be the way to go: seems to be popular and supported.  I still don't have it working perfectly but it has more promise.

```
 pip3 install jupytext

 jupytext --to notebook   /git/prdnlp/python/readct.py

 jupyter-notebook /git/prdnlp/python/readct.ipynb
```

The `markdown` cell is denoted as

```
#%% [markdown]
```

So the code now looks like:

```py
#%%
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf


#%% [markdown]

"""
## Clinical Trials Postgres queries

We are using data from [ClinicalTrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?term=recurrent&cond=Glioblastoma+Multiforme&age_v=&gndr=&type=&rslt=With&Search=Apply)

 - The data is synced to the AACT database daily
 - The conditions and interventions are identified within specific tables

"""
#%%
ct = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/SearchResults.tsv',delimiter='\t')
ctIdsDf = sqldf("select `NCT Number` nct_id, * from ct order by 1")
ctIds = ctIdsDf['nct_id']

#%%
```

Notice that the triple quotes do still show up in the output: so I'm unclear as to how to get them to be "stripped" out by the `jupytext`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `#%% md` flag. For example:

```
#%% md 
Normal Text
```

Other formats include:

```
#%% md 
# Title
## Heading 1
### Heading 3
### _Bold_
### *Italics*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use three single quotes (or three double quotes) python will interpret everything between as literal text, including carriage returns, spaces, and ignoring what it would normally recognize as special characters.

So, you can embed markdown in a file, or in a script this way...

```
s = '''
This line starts at the edge and has a carriage return
  This one starts two spaces in. 
  # This one has a hashtag, which is nŃOT seen as a comment. 
  https://thisIsJustTextNow.com
'''

print(s)
```

OUTPUT:

```
This line starts at the edge and has a carriage return
  This one starts two spaces in. 
  # This one has a hashtag, which is NOT seen as a comment. 
  https://thisIsJustTextNow.com
```

Comment: That's not going to be rendered as markdown when converted by ipython

Comment: @javadba You're correct. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do. This would be the method if you were, for example, attempting to have python write out a Markdown file - without getting confused by the markdown syntax.

Comment: The need here is to have a python-friendly source file that can be converted to .ipynb by a single command.